# Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.createHandler()` in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, next.js, apollo-server

I am getting this error when trying to check if apollo graphql is working fine.
Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.createHandler()`
Note : There is a similar question ,but I am not using express [Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614523/error-you-must-await-server-start-before-calling-server-applymiddleware)

//api/graphql.js

```
  import  {  ApolloServer  }  from  "apollo-server-micro";

import  {  resolvers  }  from  "../../apis/resolver";
import  {  typeDefs  }  from  "../../apis/schemas";

const  apolloServer  =  new  ApolloServer({  typeDefs,  resolvers  });

export  const  config  =  {
    api:  {
        bodyParser:  false
    }
};

export  default  apolloServer.createHandler({ path:  "/api/graphql"  });
```

//resolver

```
import axios from "axios";

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: async () => {
      try {
        const users = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/users");
        return users.data.map(({ id, login, avatar_url }) => ({
          id,
          login,
          avatar_url
        }));
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    },
    getUser: async (_, args) => {
      try {
        const user = await axios.get(
          `https://api.github.com/users/${args.name}`
        );
        return {
          id: user.data.id,
          login: user.data.login,
          avatar_url: user.data.avatar_url
        };
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

//schema

```
import  {  gql  }  from  "apollo-server-micro"; 

export  const  typeDefs  =  gql`
    type  User {
        id: ID
        login: String
        avatar_url: String
    }

    type  Query {
        getUsers: [User]
        getUser(name: String!): User!
    }`
```

Answer (score 22):

This works for me, copied from the guys at prisma.

```js
import Cors from "micro-cors";
import schema from "graphql/schema";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { PageConfig } from "next";
import { createContext } from "graphql/context";

export const config: PageConfig = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const cors = Cors();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: createContext,
  schema,
});

const startServer = server.start();

export default cors(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.end();
    return false;
  }

  await startServer;
  await server.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" })(req, res);
});
```

Comment: Absolute rockstar! I've been looking for this for so long, thank you! Could you please link the original source as well?

Comment: @JanRichter glad I could help. Here you have the source: https://youtu.be/RJpevpbC4YY?t=323

Comment: Any explanation why is this needed also for localhost?

Comment: @igo I think it is because next treats routes as lambdas so things are re-created on every call. Calling server.start() outside the handler functions makes next.js cache the `startServer` variable. .start() returns a promise so if that promise is cached, calling `await startServer` wont have a penalty on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using an integration package for a non-serverless
framework (like `express`, `micro`), you must `await` a call to `start` immediately after creating your `ApolloServer`, before attaching it to your web framework and starting to accept requests. This [assertStarted()](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L598) method will assert if the server is started. For more info, see [comments of source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L340)

There are some examples, see [apollo-server-micro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-micro) package and [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/middleware/#apollo-server-micro)

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-micro');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    sayHello: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    sayHello(parent, args, context) {
      return 'Hello World!';
    },
  },
};

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
module.exports = apolloServer.start().then(() => {
  return apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/data' });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. This is a known bug with an open issue so that for now, you can downgrade apollo-server-micro@^2.

My package.json is now as follows and it works flawlessly.

```
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-server-micro": "2.25.0",
  "graphql": "^15.6.1",
  "micro": "^9.3.4",
  "mongoose": "^6.0.10",
  "next": "11.1.2",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2" }
```